# getJSON and ajax data limit?

Tags: jquery, ajax, getjson

I am using the following function to load data. For some reason it is not working for very large datasets (100M) but it works for my toy datasets. Is there some sort of size limit or parameter I have not found that will enable me to load these large datasets?:

```
function loadData(nameOfFile){

  $(function(){
          $.getJSON("//www.yadayada" + nameOfFile + ".json",function(data){
              //load the data into new objects

          }).error(function(){
              console.log('error loading data!');
          });
  });

  console.log("done with getJSON");
}
```

And it is part of an ajax call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
success: function (result) { 

      //do stuff

    }
});
```

$.ajax();
  loadData(file);

Comment: FYI, `console.log("done with getJSON");` will be called before the response is received.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a size limitation for HTTP. The spec doesn't impose size limits.  But the server setup definitely does.

The amount of data available for your request will usually be limited by either the web server or the programming technology used to process the form submission...

It has nothing to do with ajax.

Check the server you are running, what server-side tech you are using etc etc

Comment: what do you mean by " or the programming technology used to process the form submission..."?

Comment: I mean whatever server side technology you are using...ie PHP, ASP, Python etc....they can all set their own transfer limits

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to you but have a look at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427